# CPU Temperature in Python 3 (Linux & Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking to get the CPU Temperature in Python 3. Can be different lib's but I need one for Linux & Windows.

psutil.sensors_temperature only seems to work on Python 2. I haven't been able to find any other suitable alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You can install `psutil` in python3 using `pip`. On Ubuntu, you might need the `python-dev` packages for some header files required by `psutil`. You might also need to use `pip3` instead of `pip`.

```
Python 3.8.3 (default, May 17 2020, 18:15:42) 
[GCC 10.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psutil             
>>> psutil.sensors_temperatures()
{'nvme': [shwtemp(label='Composite', current=37.85, high=84.85, critical=84.85), shwtemp(label='Sensor 1', current=37.85, high=65261.85, critical=65261.85), shwtemp(label='Sensor 2', current=43.85, high=65261.85, critical=65261.85)], 'k10temp': [shwtemp(label='Tctl', current=55.0, high=None, critical=None), shwtemp(label='Tdie', current=55.0, high=None, critical=None), shwtemp(label='Tccd1', current=39.5, high=None, critical=None)], 'nct6797': [shwtemp(label='SYSTIN', current=42.0, high=80.0, critical=80.0), shwtemp(label='PCH_CPU_TEMP', current=0.0, high=None, critical=None), shwtemp(label='CPUTIN', current=37.0, high=115.0, critical=115.0), shwtemp(label='AUXTIN0', current=38.5, high=115.0, critical=115.0), shwtemp(label='AUXTIN1', current=-128.0, high=None, critical=None), shwtemp(label='AUXTIN2', current=60.0, high=None, critical=None), shwtemp(label='AUXTIN3', current=-3.0, high=None, critical=None), shwtemp(label='SMBUSMASTER 0', current=55.0, high=None, critical=None), shwtemp(label='PCH_CHIP_CPU_MAX_TEMP', current=0.0, high=None, critical=None), shwtemp(label='PCH_CHIP_TEMP', current=0.0, high=None, critical=None)]}
>>>
```

You can just simply import it and it should work.

Comment: Psutil sensors_temperatures is only supported on ubuntu I believe. (Windows Error:`AttributeError: module 'psutil' has no attribute 'sensors_temperatures'`) 

And that too only on Python 2. (Python3 returns an empty array)

Comment: Have you tried following the installation instructions [here](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/INSTALL.rst)? `psutil` should support WIndows and Python 3 according to the documentation.

Comment: Also, I believe `sensors_temperatures()` is a method rather than an attribute, so you'll need round brackets.

Comment: However, this specific function isn't supported on windows. https://file.coffee/u/wiu5hfMd7.png